# compile and execute python code in webbrowser compiler

Tags: python, web-browser, cloud-storage

I cannot load Anaconda (or equivalent) onto my machine and would like to practice python coding through a web browser.  Additionally, I would like to work with a dataset on a cloud

Is there a cloud-service or other solution that will let me do both?

If not, can I practice python through a web browser with data on my local machine?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of possibilities:

- There are services such as [Python Anywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) that allow you to use python in a web browser *initially free* & [Repl IT](https://repl.it/languages/python3) *also supports other languages*
- You can use the binder service to try Jupyter Notebooks or JupyterLab
- Services that let you run python in Jupyter Notebooks such as:

  - [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/pricing/?nc2=h_ql_pr)
  - [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/?v=48092-1914) (see [Azure Notebooks](https://notebooks.azure.com/))
  - [Google Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb)
  - [IBM Watson Studio](https://www.ibm.com/uk-en/marketplace/watson-studio)
  - [Code Ocean](https://codeocean.com/)
  - [Kogence](https://kogence.com/app/docs/JupyterNotebook)
  - [Kyso](https://kyso.io/)
  - [Mode](https://mode.com/)
  - [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/)
- You can install [WinPython](https://winpython.github.io/) to a USB stick and run python from there - *always free*
- You could get a Raspberry Pi which comes with Python pre-installed if you get one of the kits that has the SD card with Rasperian installed.